# Support generic path for script as sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I've some script which doing something like

```
tar -xvf /home/i557956/htp-assembly.tar -C /home/i557956/b_myFolder
```

now I've change it to be more generic

```
tar -xvf $HOME/htp-assembly.tar -C $HOME/b_myFolder
```

This is working as expexted but when I eneter and **sudo** (sudo -i)

I got error that the file (tar) are not found since it is tring to find it under
which is doesnt exist, it is under `/home/i557956/htp-assembly.tar`

**/root/htp-assembly.tar**

**and I get this error** :Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

There is a way to overcome it somehow ? to support some hibrid solution that if you in sudo do this otherwise do that...

**UPDATE:**

I do the following as meetTitan provide as answer and it doesnt work.

```
1 . I enter the to system with sudo -i
2. create script file under /home/i557956 
3. update the code like the answer below 
homeDirArg="$*"
tar -xvf $homeDirArg/htp-assembly.tar -C $homeDirArg/b_myFolder
4. run the script ( .myScript $HOME ) and still got the same error as above, any idea?
```

Comment: @MeetTitan - Can you give an example please?

Comment: Er, the *whole point* of `sudo -i` is that it's a login shell for the target user.  If you want variables including `HOME` to be preserved, you should use `sudo -s`.